# Error installingthe Python Fuel SDK Library, Windows

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, fuel-sdk, python, windows8

I am new to Fuel SDK development and currently trying to **pip install** the FuelSDK library so that I can practice making REST/SOAP calls.

I have entered the following command into my **power shell**:

```
pip install FuelSDK
```

On running this command, I recieve the following error:

[image: Fuel SDK Installation Error]

I will appreciate guidance on how to resolve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon closer investigation, I found that there are issues with the **sudo** module  for **Python 3**.

A work around has been created, and it can be installed by entering the following into your terminal:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python.git@v1.0.0
```

This should install sucessfully.

Reference: [Github](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python/issues/54)